# Export Socket server DLL that uses boost shared_array and import it in a C# .NET Application

Tags: c#, c++, .net, boost

I am trying to export -to a DLL- the software of a socket server application written in C++ using boost library. I aim to add this DLL as a reference to a new .NET C# application. 
The main problem that I face is: to export or convert the boost Shared_Array to a compatible type for .NET C# applications. The Boost Shared_Array type is used as a buffer for the data transmitted via the socket server. 
Can anyone help? Any code snippet is welcomed.

Comment: In fact I think your question is unrelated to `shared_array` (not to mention Shared_Array doesn't exist); you want to know how to pass raw memory buffers (logically: `(char* const, size_t)`) to an interop client. What's the platform? Can you use c++/cli? Do you prefer P/Invoke or COM interop?

Comment: One of the output of this software is a data array declared as boost::shared_array. I need to export this array. To be precise, this is declared as boost::shared_array<unsigned char> data_pnt_. I use Visual Studio 2013, boost 1.55.0 I intent to use c++/cli to create a wrapper for the dll. And then I want to create a C# project to refer to this dll and have access to the data_pnt_ array.

Comment: Are you aware of what unmanaged code is and how the extern keyword works?